# How to find item count in a SPFolder?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a List that stores items in a folder hierarchy.

I notice that `SPFolder.Files.Count` is always zero.

Is there a way to find out how many list items are there in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are looking for direct children and not descendants (like items within a sub-folder).

Do you also want to include sub-folders in the count? In which case you can use: `SPFolder.ItemCount`.

If you just want only the direct child listItems which are not subfolders then you can do something like the following:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(mySPSite))
{
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList list = web.Lists[myList];
    SPFolder folderInstance = list.RootFolder.SubFolders[folderUrl];

    SPQuery query = new SPQuery() ;
    query.Folder = folderInstance;

    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query) ;

    Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
}
```

I haven't tried it. You might have to add a where clause to eliminate folders, if the query is returning that.

If you want to include all list-items, even within subfolders, set the `SPQuery.ViewAttributes` field as `query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\""`;

Comment: Yes, I need item count without sub-folders. Is it possible to get this without firing a query?

Comment: Don't know. You might have some luck with SPFolder.Item.ListItems.

Comment: Nope. SPFolder.Items.ListItems didn't help. I used your solution as I could not find what I was looking for :) Thanks!

Comment: If this answer does not resolved your query then why this is as accepted? It will misguide others!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get the SPListItem from the SPFolder and check the values from the SPBuiltInFieldId.ItemChildCount and SPBuiltInFieldId.FolderChildCount fields?

Something like this:

```
SPFolder folder = ...;
int? noOfItems = folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.ItemChildCount] as int?;
int? noOfFolders = folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FolderChildCount] as int?;
```

See

[SPBuiltInFieldId.ItemChildCount Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.itemchildcount)

[SPBuiltInFieldId.FolderChildCount Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.folderchildcount)

for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[From Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557257.aspx)

> Using the SPList.ItemCount property is
>   the recommended way to retrieve the
>   number of items in a list. As a side
>   effect of tuning this property for
>   performance, however, the property can
>   occasionally return unexpected
>   results. For example, if you require
>   the exact number of items, you should
>   use ...

I wonder if the same applies to SPFolder.ItemCount ?

Comment: SPFolder does not have ItemCount property defined!