# How to programmatically get a Discussion Board's reply from a webpart for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm building a visual webpart for SharePoint 2010 and I need to get a reply from a Discussion Board programmatically (asp.net).

Because I get the folder Discussion 1 (inside a Discussion Board, let's say) and then I want to browse its files but I get `files.count = 0`, while I perfectly get the Document Library's files using that code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = folder;
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

See also:

- [How to find item count in a SPFolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923899/how-to-find-item-count-in-a-spfolder)
- [Traversing SharePoint List Folder Hierarchies](http://blog.krichie.com/2007/01/30/traversing-sharepoint-list-folder-hierarchies/)