# Count items in specific folder in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have sharepoint 2010 site on intranet with document library. Document library has folder structure with sub folders. I need number documents in specific subfolder . I know that this field exists in document library but i don't know how i use them for specific subfolder in another list where this field will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Where and how do you want to use the count? In code, display in a list?

In a list you can edit the view and just add the "Item Child Count" column to the view.

Several code solutions here: [How to find item count in a SPFolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923899/how-to-find-item-count-in-a-spfolder)

If using 2013: From code using the REST API see here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145219/how-to-get-itemchildcount-of-documentset-folder-using-rest-api

Comment: I want that this field use in status list for checling that documents exists or not

Comment: Are you wanting to see the library's folder count property as a column in another list?

Comment: Yes, based on value of count property in status list(another list) i want show status green